# Is it possible to switch to other android build?

Tags: android, intellij-13

I am still newbie in android i just want to ask if this is possible if i have application android created in API 8 then tried to change to API 19,does my application will not cause trouble?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: there will probably be things you have to change yes. that is why you should always target the highest API with your `minSdk` set.

Comment: @tyczj, i'm still learning on this android ,i could not get what you mean...where do i set those things?

Comment: in the manifest `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />`

Comment: ah i.c...thank you so much...so if i will set this, my application will be fine?even i keep updating the targetSdkVersion?

Comment: no there will be things you will probably have to change, just do it and test your application